# put something in .txt file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ftp, text-files

I have (finally) managed to send a txt file via ftp to my server! YAY!

It is an empty .txt file at the moment. My question is - How do I put something in that .txt file. I can store NSStrings from UITextFields, but how do i put them strings in the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `writeToFile:` method. Perhaps this may help.

[Problem writing string to a file ...(iPhone SDK )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443184/problem-writing-string-to-a-file-iphone-sdk)

Comment: 1 more thing - this works fine on simulator - put doesnt on the device - any thoughts?

Comment: What path are you trying to write to? You need to be careful to write only in your sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

A few classes to get you started:

[NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSString's path methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

[NSFileHandle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)